# how to add Transform Matrix to LinearGradient in Container?

Tags: flutter, linear-gradients, radius

I am adding LinearGradient to Container. I also wants to add following to CSS:

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 52.61%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);
```

But I am not getting correct way to add this to linear gradient.

Comment: use `transform` optional parameter

Comment: @pskink can you share more details